# Geonames country name

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geocoding

I'm using the geonames.org free service and I'm getting long country names like:

Kingdom of Norway, Commonwealth of Australia, Democratic republic of Congo

This does not correspond to the country name list here

http://www.geonames.org/countries/

How can I make it display only Norway, Australia, Congo and not the whole title?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like geonames sends longer country names for English if you don't specify the language. So

```
http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=oslo&lang=&username=username&callback=?
```

must become (specify language code)

```
http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=oslo&lang=en&username=username&callback=?
```

or else you get weird results.